In VS 2022 get the message Hot Reload - Changes Not Supported but I haven't changed anything
I keep getting a Hot Reload - Changes Not Supported in VS 2022 on my ASP.NET project, but I haven't made any changes.  I've tried doing a clean followed by a rebuild solution, but I still get it the message.
Yesterday, I tried clicking on the Rebuild and apply changes button and it fixed it, but that hasn't worked today.
Is there any way to see what file Visual Studio thinks has changed?
Any idea what I can try?
Thanks

Not sure if it's related, but I just changed my solutions start up project from multiple (but with only one actually selected) to just my web project and I didn't get the error this time.  I've tried restarting Visual Studio and it hasn't fixed it in the past.

I think it was related to  https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Hot-Reload---Changes-not-supported-with/10525666?sort=active&type=idea
I had:
.NET SDK:
 Version:           8.0.100
 Commit:            57efcf1350
 Workload version:  8.0.100-manifests.8d38d0ccMaybe I need  .NET SDK 8.0.201? (edited) 

Updating to dotnet-sdk-8.0.301-win-x64 seems to have fixed the problem for me.
